# Android app with setVolume.... extending TabActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, audio-streaming, tabactivity

hi i've an app where i want to implement  `setVolumeControlStream` 
but i can't because my class extends TabActivity not Activity. what shall i do ??

Answer (score 0):

`setVolumeControlStream()` is available on `TabActivity`, because `TabActivity` inherits from `Activity`.